# Para que serve os { } no código abaixo? e qual a definição?

Tags: php

```
$objeto->{'getEndereco' . ucfirst($tipo)}()->getCep();
```

Comment: Parece que você quer fazer isso:

$objeto->getEnderecoComercial()->getCep();

Comment: exato, mas qual a definição? e é uma boa pratica?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Documentação oficial](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)

Serve basicamente para definir o início e o final do nome do método que deve ser invocado. Como o nome varia conforme o valor de `$tipo`, fazer apenas:

```
$objeto->'getEndereco' . ucfirst($tipo)()->getCep();
```

Irá gerar um erro de sintaxe, pois o PHP não saberá o que fazer com uma constante após o operador `->`.

> Syntax error, unexpected ''getEndereco'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

Veja que o próprio erro diz que seria esperado uma `T_STRING`, que neste caso será apenas `getEndereco`, sem aspas, ou uma variável ou o caractere `{`. Ou seja, os caracteres `{}` indicam ao PHP para interpretar o valor interno como o nome do método e não como uma constante qualquer.

Executar o código apresentado:

```
$objeto->{'getEndereco' . ucfirst($tipo)}()->getCep();
```

É análogo a fazer:

```
$endereco = call_user_func([$objeto, 'getEndereco' . ucfirst($tipo)]);
$endereco->getCep();
```

Porém, em certas situações fica mais prático apenas encadear as chamadas utilizando `{}`. É possível, ainda, encadear essa notação. Por exemplo:

```
$foo = "Hello";
$bar = "foo";

echo "${${'bar'}} world"; // Hello world
```

Pois `{'bar'}` é interpretado como `bar`, então `${'bar'}` é tratado como a variável `$bar`, cujo valor é `"foo"`. Logo, `{${'bar'}}` será interpretado como `foo` e `${${'bar'}}` será tratado como a variável `$foo`, exibindo seu conteúdo, `"Hello"`.

---

Em versões PHP 7+ é possível, também, utilizar `{}` junto com `use` para importar múltiplas classes de um mesmo *namespace*:

```
use Meu\Namespace\{ClasseA, ClasseB, ClasseC};
```

Em versões anteriores seria necessário fazer:

```
use Meu\Namespace\ClasseA;
use Meu\Namespace\ClasseB;
use Meu\Namespace\ClasseC;
```

Comment: Não conheço reflection do java, vou dar uma pesquisada, vlw.

Comment: @ALE_ROM, para mais fonte sobre `reflection` em Java: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37632/4438007; mas como eu e o AndersonCarlosWoss conversamos no chat, é muito forçada a comparação, até removi meu comentário que comparava

Answer (score 4):

Isto serve para accesar o objeto de forma dinâmica. Vamos supor que o $tipo tenha o seguinte conteúdo:

```
$tipo = 'Residencial';

// Forma correta dinâmica
$objeto->{'getEndereco' . ucfirst($tipo)}()->getCep();

// Forma correta direta
$objeto->getEnderecoResidencial()->getCep();

// Todas as duas opções acima irão acessar a função do objeto e obter o getCep:
$objeto->getEnderecoResidencial()->getCep;

// Formas INcorretas
$objeto->'getEndereco' . ucfirst($tipo)()->getCep();
$objeto['getEndereco' . ucfirst($tipo)]()->getCep();
$objeto['getEnderecoResidencial']()->getCep();
```

Answer (score 4):

Em `PHP` há `N` formas de se escrever uma [`string`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php), uma delas é a chamada `Sintaxe complexa`.

O nome não é realmente devido a complexidade da sintaxe, mas sim devido à expressões complexas que podem ser escritas desta maneira.

Conforme a própria documentação:

> Qualquer variável escalar, elemento de um array ou propriedade de um
>   objeto com uma representação de uma string pode ser incluída com essa
>   sintaxe. Simplesmente escreva a expressão da mesma forma como
>   apareceria fora da string e então coloque-o entre { e }. Já que que {
>   não pode escapado, esta sintaxe será somente reconhecida quando o $
>   seguir, imediatamente, o {. Use {\$ para obter um literal {$.