# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Não estou conseguindo descobrir onde esta o erro. Acredito que esta na cara, mas não consigo achar!

```
$inserir = $conexao->query("INSERT INTO cadastro (nome, sobrenome, email, senha, contrata, trabalha, status) VALUE (
          $_POST['nome'],
          $_POST['sobrenome'],
          $_POST['email'],
          $_POST['senha'],
          $_POST['contrata'],
          $_POST['trabalha'],
          'N'
    )");
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
>   expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or
>   number (T_NUM_STRING) in

Comment: Coloque todos os valores POST entre chaves.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Vou fazer, mas porque entre chaves? Não era assim...

Comment: Você está tentando injetar uma expressão PHP dentro de uma string. Para que o PHP entenda que é uma expressão, precisa utilizar as chaves.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/217819/5878

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que o problema é que ele não está identificando as variáveis corretamente.

Tente passa-las usando concatenação:

```
$inserir = $conexao->query("INSERT INTO cadastro (nome, sobrenome, email, senha, contrata, trabalha, status) VALUE (
          '".$_POST['nome']."',
          '".$_POST['sobrenome']."',
          '".$_POST['email']."',
          '".$_POST['senha']."',
          '".$_POST['contrata']."',
          '".$_POST['trabalha']."',
          'N'
    )");
```

Ou como o Anderson sugeriu, utilizando chaves nas variáveis:

```
$inserir = $conexao->query("INSERT INTO cadastro (nome, sobrenome, email, senha, contrata, trabalha, status) VALUE (
          '{$_POST['nome']}',
          '{$_POST['sobrenome']}',
          '{$_POST['email']}',
          '{$_POST['senha']}',
          '{$_POST['contrata']}',
          '{$_POST['trabalha']}',
          'N'
    )");
```

Comment: E provavelmente falta as aspas simples aí para definir como string no MySQL.

Comment: Deu certo, mas apareceu esse erro `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function close() on boolean in`

Comment: Aí já é outro problema completamente diferente.

Comment: @Tiago Acho que isso não tem nada a ver com a query referenciada na pergunta, veja a linha do erro. Caso não consiga resolver, recomendo que [crie outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).