# site php retorna >

Tags: php

Minha pagina esta retornando `>` sinal de menor quando add o seguinte codigo que está comentado:

```
<form name="form_import" id="form_import" method="post" action="<?php echo $_endereco ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table class="formulario">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="cabecalho">
        <th colspan="2">
          Agraves - importar
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <label>Tipos de Agreve</label>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>  <th></th>
        <td>
          <a href="upload_foto/agrave_pdf.php">
            <ul>
              <li>Agrave 4 salarios</li>
              <li>agrave 10 salarios</li>
            </ul>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <label>Arquivo </label>
        </th>
        <td>
          <input type="file" name="arquivo" id="nome_arquivo"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="rodape">
        <td colspan="2">
          <input type="hidden" name="advogado" id="acao" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?login=$_SESSION['_codigo_usuario']"; ?>">
          <button type="submit" src="mgm/importa.png" alt="Importar" class="elemento_a_direita"/>Importar
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: tentei reproduzir o erro e não obtive sucesso, você pode disponibilizar um trecho melhor do código?

Answer (score 1):

Seu código está errado na linha:

```
<input type="hidden" name="advogado" id="acao" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?login=$_SESSION['_codigo_usuario']"; ?>">
```

> Veja (não) funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/9yJLgB).

Se a intenção é concatenar o valor da sessão na *string*, o mais simples é retirá-la de dentro da mesma:

```
<input type="hidden" name="advogado" id="acao" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?login=".$_SESSION['_codigo_usuario']; ?>">
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/NeyguZ).

Ou utilizar as chaves para formatar corretamente a *string*:

```
<input type="hidden" name="advogado" id="acao" value="<?php echo "{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?login={$_SESSION['_codigo_usuario']}"; ?>">
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/VDqUiX).

Pergunta relacionada:

[Para que serve os { } no código abaixo? e qual a definição?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/217819/5878)

Answer (score -1):

tente remover as duas barras após a concatenação:

```
   <form name="form_import" id="form_import" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?login=$_SESSION['_codigo_usuario']"; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Mas as duas barras é o que define o comentário. Por quê removê-las?

Comment: E por que você teria um comentário no meio de uma linha de código?

Comment: @Sergio o porquê eu não sei, mas é uma sintaxe válida e documentada. Veja um [exemplo](https://ideone.com/qaDRz8) e a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.basic-syntax.comments.php) sobre os comentários.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, todos os exemplos que você mostrou, os comentários estão em um final de linha. No caso do código acima, o comentário está no meio de um comando, fazendo com que todo o resto do código seja considerado um comentário também. O php ignora de onde começa o comentário _"...até o final da linha ou do bloco..."_, como diz na própria documentação.

Comment: @Sergio Exato. Inicialmente o autor colocou que o código estava comentado dando a entender que a intenção era que ele fosse ignorado.